# Need to render charts in my view but it returns Undefined variable: chart

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, charts, highcharts

Need to render charts in my view but it returns Undefined variable: chart (View: C:\wamp64\www\adminkik\resources\views\home.blade.php) . 
here is what i put in the view

```
<div class="col-lg-12"> {!! $chart->html() !!} </div>
```

and  my HomeController my HomeController@index is like this

```
$chart = Charts::multi('bar', 'material') ->title("My Cool Chart")
->dimensions(0, 400)
->dataset('Element 1', [5,20,100])
->dataset('Element 2', [15,30,80])
->dataset('Element 3', [25,10,40]) 
->labels(['One', 'Two', 'Three']); 

return view('home',['charts'=>$chart]);
```

I need help please

Comment: you have returned with different key and you are using variable with diffrerent name, please return like  `return view('home',['chart'=>$chart]);` or  use `{!! $charts->html() !!}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The name of the variable you are setting for your view is 'charts'

try

```
<div class="col-lg-12"> {!! $charts->html() !!} </div>
```

Comment: You're welcome, glad to help. Please accept the answer as solution if it solved your issue.